# php variable assignment to display html & php variable

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm having a php noob moment, im looking for a smaller more compact solution to concatenate the "$content" variable which is being echoed as the main content in an external "layout.php" file.

```
<?php

require_once("Controller/comment_control.php");
$comment = new COMMENT();

$title = "Customer Reviews";
$content = '<div class="comment_box">'   ;
$content .=  $comment->getComments(); 
$content .=  '</div>';
```

any help condensing this ugly mess is appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for suggestions on coding style, the correct place to post is CodeReview.stackexchange.com. SO is for help fixing problems in code.

Comment: note taken,  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, encompassing the php call in parenthesis got the end result i wanted

```
$content = '<div class="comment_box">'  .  ($comment->getComments() ) .  '</div>';
```

Comment: Your original code should work exactly the same. If you're seeing the source code, it's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf()

[SPRINTF](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Example:

```
$content = sprintf('<div class="comment_box">%s</div>', $comment->getComments());
```

Comment: Why would this work any differently from his original code?

Comment: Because he asked: im looking for a smaller more compact solution to concatenate the "$content" variable

Comment: I thought his problem was that he's seeing the source code on the web page.

Comment: You're right there's 2 questions in the question of OP.

Comment: edited the op to clean up confusion. it was not intended to be two questions.  Thanks for your replies, I can't believe I forgot about sprintf();